# Workaround for pandas merge error "unhashable type: dict"

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

i have 2 data frames ds and dk and want to merge that with a common column result using the merge command:

```
result = pd.merge(ds,dk,on='result')
```

but the result column is actually a dictionary and resulting in the error:

```
 "unhashable type: dict"
```

what is the possible solution for merging these frames? Can the result column be changed to a string type and then be merged along the column?
I tried using `dk['result']= str(dk['result'])` and `ds['result']= str(ds['result'])` to convert then and merge but it did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ds = pd.DataFrame({'result':[{'a':1,'b':1},{'a':3,'b':9},{'a':7,'b':5}],
                   'a':[0,1,0]})

dk = pd.DataFrame({'result':[{'a':1,'b':1},{'a':3,'b':9},{'a':7,'b':5}],
                   'b':[2,2,2]})

ds['result'] = ds['result'].astype(str) # transorm dict to str
dk['result'] = dk['result'].astype(str) # transorm dict to str

result = pd.merge(ds,dk,on='result')
result['result'] = result['result'].apply(eval) # comeback im dict format
```